# How to optimize this entity framework code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, query-optimization, local

I'm fetching movie meta data from and API and adding them to database using entity framework using the following code

This code this taking upto 20% CPU when called for one movie. I'm using one context for one insert.
Add() and DBSet.Local.Where(..) methods are the most expensive here. How can I optimize the code to reduce CPU.

Update: On code profiling I found DBSet.Local.Where(..) is where the CPU is eating up. My reason to call DBSet.Local.Where is to find out if I've already added that object (person) so that I don't re-add it. Thoughts?

Comment: It looks to me like you're holding a single `DbContext` globally and reusing it again and again. This is bad. You should `new` one up in local scope, do small amounts of work with it, `SaveChanges`, then `Dispose` and discard, ideally using a `using` statement and keeping it in *local* scope. These contexts aren't designed to be long-lived.

Comment: With lazy loading, this code must be making tens, possibly more queries per insert. Lazy loading and performance don't sit well together.

Comment: this is a asp.net website. i do have a long live context. but i'm not using that in this. a new context is supplied for each movie addorupdate call.

Comment: while lazy loading could be an issue, code profiler shows it's this line of code which is consuming CPU most: var LocalDBPerson = Context.Persons.Local.Where(My => My.ID == APICast.Id).FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 0):

This `Movies.Where(My => My.ID == Movie.Id).FirstOrDefault()` can be optimize by calling `Movies.Find(Movie.Id)`.

> Finds an entity with the given primary key values. If an entity with the given primary key values exists in the context, then it is returned immediately without making a request to the store. 
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx

I don't see any optimizations for the `Add()`